# How can I install this addon properly

Tags: add-on, camera

The addon is an AR app for using your iPhone as a virtual camera in blender
it works for other people and I ensured that I was using the very latest blender version.

I get the following error when i check the box to enable the addon:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.93\2.93\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 351, in enable
mod = **import**(module_name)
File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\virtucamera_blender_*init*_.py", line 37, in 
from .virtucamera_blender import *
File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\virtucamera_blender\virtucamera_blender.py", line 39, in 
from .virtucamera import VCBase, VCServer
File "C:\Users\Lukas\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.93\scripts\addons\virtucamera_blender\virtucamera_*init*_.py", line 42, in 
from .vc_core import VCServer
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtucamera_blender.virtucamera.vc_core'

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you download the version of the Add-On that matches your version of Blender.  [Here's the version for 2.93](https://github.com/shycats/VirtuCameraBlender/releases/tag/v1.1.0_2.93)
2. Do *not* unzip the file.  Stick it in your add-ons directory.
3. Follow [these instructions](https://virtucamera.com/installation-in-blender/)

- Select *Preferences* from the *Edit Menu*
- Navigate to *Add-ons*.
- left click *Install*
- navigate the file browser to your add-ons directory and select **VirtuCameraBlender-cp39-windows-x64-v1.1.0.zip** if you're on Windows.  Replace 'windows-x64' with the correct name for your OS if you're not.
- *3D View: VirtuCamera* will show up in your add-ons list.  Select it.

That's it, you're done.